# Удаление младших битов

Tags: c++, visual-c++, битовые-операции

Имеется слово

uint32_t word

Как удалить два младших бита? Именно удалить, а не обнулить, чтобы размер слова понизился до 30 бит.

Comment: word >>= 2; Но количество бит останется прежним - 32 (uint32_t ) :)))

Comment: Размер слова измениться не может... Можно только выполнить сдвиг, например.

Comment: Изменить размер вы можете только виртуально. Для описания поля заведите структуру из 2-х элементов: offset -- начало поля и width -- размер поля. Далее вы манипулируете  битами поля, используя его описание. Тогда для изменения размера вам будет нужно лишь изменить размер поля. Естественно, эти 2 элементы можно и упаковать в одну целочисленную переменную (по 5 бит на элемент)